# Changing facebook application name

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have written a simple facebook application using PHP SDK. Application works well but application name (main title which is tagged this on this image : http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/e/2/upload/fd7d8c6f.jpg ) looks as "php-sdk". How can I change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the image you're showing is when you try to share a link to your application, correct? That title and other info is set in the headers under specific Facebook metadata.

Check out their documentation on the meta tags at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

The specific tag for the title is `<meta property="og:title" content="[your title here]"/>`, this will be found in the HTML `<head>` area of your application.

Answer (score 10):

You can change the name of your application under the developer settings http://developers.facebook.com/apps click on edit settings and the first page should allow you to update the display name. You can also change your canvas url by changing the namespace.